# Merge/Join two Dataframes, one with IP addresses, one with IP Networks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ip-address

I have two dataframes, one containing IP addresses (`df_ip`), one containing IP networks (`df_network`).
The IP's and Networks are of the type `ipaddress.ip_address` and `ipaddress.ip_network`, which enables checking if an IP lies in the Network (`ip in network`).

The dataframes look as follows:

```
df_ip:
    IP
0   10.10.10.10
1   10.10.20.10
2   10.10.20.20

df_network:
    NETWORK         NETWORK_NAME
0   10.10.10.0/28   Subnet1
1   10.10.20.0/27   Subnet2
```

**I want to merge/join `df_ip` with `df_network`, adding the name of the network in which the IP lies per row.**
For this small instance, it should return the following:

```
df_merged:
    IP            NETWORK_NAME
0   10.10.10.10   Subnet1
1   10.10.20.10   Subnet2
2   10.10.20.20   Subnet2
```

My actual dataframes are much larger, so id prefer to not use for-loops to maintain efficiency.
How can I best achieve this? If this requires changing the datatypes, that's okay.

**Note:** I've added code below to create the data for convenience.

```py
import pandas as pd
import ipaddress

# Create small IP DataFrame
values_ip = [ipaddress.ip_address('10.10.10.10'),
             ipaddress.ip_address('10.10.20.10'),
             ipaddress.ip_address('10.10.20.20')]

df_ip = pd.DataFrame()
df_ip['IP'] = values_ip

# Create small Network DataFrame
values_network = [ipaddress.ip_network('10.10.10.0/28'),
                  ipaddress.ip_network('10.10.20.0/27')]
names_network = ['Subnet1',
                 'Subnet2']

df_network = pd.DataFrame()
df_network['NETWORK'] = values_network
df_network['NETWORK_NAME'] = names_network
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an efficient way to avoid any loops is to use numpy arrays to check where `ip & netmask == network_address`, which is how to check whether an ip lies within the network.

note that this returns only the first matching network name

```
import numpy as np
net_masks = df_network.NETWORK.apply(lambda x: int(x.netmask)).to_numpy()
network_addresses = df_network.NETWORK.apply(lambda x: int(x.network_address)).to_numpy()

def get_first_network(ip):
    is_in_network = int(ip) & net_masks == network_addresses
    indices = np.argwhere(is_in_network)
    if indices.size>0:
        return df_network.loc[int(indices[0]), 'NETWORK_NAME' ]
    else:
        None

df_ip['network_name'] = df_ip.IP.apply(get_first_network)
```

which results in:

```
            IP network_name
0  10.10.10.10      Subnet1
1  10.10.20.10      Subnet2
2  10.10.20.20      Subnet2
```